# WSO2 Carbon database setup

Tags: wso2

Having to troubleshoot a time out issue when calling our WSO2 carbon setup. I know practically nothing about WSO2 but have read that the H2 database supplied is not suitable for production. Although a H2 database is still used for the local registry.

Taking a look at repository\conf\datasources\master-datasources.xml it appears that we are still using the local H2 database for the WSO2_CARBON_DB.

```
    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        H2
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
        SQL Server
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2UM_DB</name>
        SQL Server
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2REG_DB</name>
        SQL Server
    </datasource>   

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
        H2
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>JAGH2</name>
        h2
    </datasource>
```

Can anyone tell me if this set up is incorrect and I need to set up another SQL server DB for WSO2_CARBON_DB, and also tell em which one of these is the "local registry"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Having a local h2 db for WSO2_CARBON_DB is OK. But in production you need to integrate a more reliable db engine such as mysql/sql server/oracle etc.. for databases other than the WSO2_CARBON_DB

Comment: Thankyou Thusitha, just to confirm then - WSO2_CARBON_DB  is the local registry that is referred to in the docs?

Comment: Yes that contains instance specific data.